# Xcode simulated size metric - difference between Freeform and None setting

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit

When I make custom UIViews I usually start by creating a xib file, and in the Attributes Inspector I change the Size property in the Simulated Metrics section to None so I can resize the view to what I want. I am wondering, is there a difference between this setting and the Freeform setting? I am using Xcode 4.6.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference when changing the Simulated Metrics is how the view looks in the interface builder. You can go to to the size tab of the inspector and change the size of the view. In iOS this is only useful when you include one view inside another view and want to see how it looks

```
UIViewcontroller *vc = ...
[self addChildViewController:vc];
[self.view addSubview:vc.view];
vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
```